# Subtract One VLOOKUP from another VLOOKUP and assign result to Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba, typeerror, vlookup

I'm trying to subtract one vlookup from another and assign the results to the range that I've decalred. I'm getting a type mismatch.

```
dim wb as workbook
dim ws1_name as range
dim ws2_range as range
dim range as range

set wb = xxxxxxx
set ws1_name as .....
(all the ranges are set)
    
Dim x As Long
    
For x = 3 To lastr_ws1
range.Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1_name, ws2_range, 27, False) - Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1_name, ws2_range, 30, False))

Next
```

Comment: What is `range`  should this be something like `...cells(x,1).value=....`

Comment: range is where the result of the subtraction will be put into. I put: Dim range as range and..... set range = Range("N3:N20")

Comment: That wont do it, you need to put the vlookup formulas themselves in, or if you want the value in there use your loop to add each.   You need to filldown "=vlookup(1)-vlookup(2)'" i think here

Comment: Your incomplete/pseudocode makes it a little difficult to tell what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: I would highly suggest performing each `VLookup` and assigning the found value into a VBA variable. This makes it much easier to check what you've found during development, AND makes your code so much easier to read. It will not slow your code down at all. Then subtract those two variables and store the result.

Comment: Also, ***NEVER*** name a variable `range`. It's reserved by VBA as an object name and you'll confuse yourself and everyone else.